# Ubuntu bash command wc

Tags: ubuntu-9.10

What is the option in "wc" command to view without showing erros message

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? What do you mean by "without showing erros *[I assume that's meant to be 'error']* message"?

Comment: Please give us the exact command you are typing, and the exact output of the command, highlighting the error messages that you do not wish to see.

Answer (score 1):

Try redirecting the error output to `/dev/null`:

```
wc whatever 2>/dev/null
```